# Error running docker container on Google Cloud Run

Tags: docker, google-cloud-run

Google reports that Cloud Run runs Docker images without problems, but in practice this is not what happens.
I'm having the following error when running a system on Cloud Run, which doesn't happen when running on Docker: "(error:02000079:rsa routines::oaep decoding error) (256/2048)".
Does anyone have any idea if there is any way around this?
I've already tried running it on "gen2", which claims to be completely compatible with Linux, but I still get the same error.

Comment: Do you have more detail on your image? Is it a x64 linux container?

Comment: Yes, its a x64 linux container based on eclipse-temurin:21-jre-jammy image with a c++ software that generate certs based on rsa specs. Its all oss, so I can create a test container to share, if you want.

Comment: Did you try to run it on a COS vm on Google Cloud? There might be some system lib missing on the runtime env.

Comment: I am confident that your problem is not caused by Cloud Run. We need to see the code that is generating your error. This can be caused by incorrect code that manages binary data as strings. This error can occur due to binary versus string encoding issues. Another possibility is a mismatch between the private and public keys (using the wrong public key to encrypt).

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere The error occurs when this lib is called ("https://github.com/cth103/libdcp"), through a CLI, presenting the following error: "Could not decrypt KDM (error:02000079:rsa routines::oaep decoding error) (256/2048)". It appears to be an openssl error generating an RSA certificate. I was running the same container that I'm running on cloud run on GKE without any problems. I run it locally without any problems too. This error only occurs in Cloud Run. Could it have something to do with the generation of random numbers?

Comment: @JohnHanley How can I explain that the error does not occur when the same container is deployed on GKE or when I run it locally?

Comment: I tried running it as a Cloud Run JOB and the error message was different: "error:02000084:rsa routines::data too large for modulus (256/2048)"
Any idea @JohnHanley and @guillaumeblaquiere?

Comment: We need to see the code that is generating your error. I have already provided a guess. Based on the error, I am certain there is a bug in your software. Follow this [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and update your post.

Comment: Hi @JohnHanley. 

I set up a container that displays the problem. 
If you run it locally on your machine, it will work. Instructions in the readme: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/16-7MvNo5izbHyuHBmYxF4z_-vrTrOnEe?usp=sharing

If you upload this container to cloud run (sevices or jobs), you will start receiving errors generated by libdcp (github.com/cth103/libdcp%22).

Comment: @JohnHanley I'm not as sure as you that the problem is in the code itself, even though it's a third-party lib, because in all other environments where we run the container, it runs without any problems (tested on GKE, DigitalOcean, AWS and locally) .
I created a repository to reproduce the problem more easily: https://github.com/fincatto/kdm-cloudrun-problem
Any idea?